# Jprofiler + Vaadin + Intellij Idea : program arguments

Tags: java, intellij-idea, vaadin, jprofiler

I have small problem. I would like to run Intellij Idea with Vaadin and JProfiler on Tomcat.
Everything is fine and works good until I wanted to add profiler to this.
In Eclipse I had 
[image: program arguments in Eclipse]
<sub>(source: [kermeta.org](http://www.kermeta.org/docs/fr.irisa.triskell.kermeta.documentation/build/html.chunked/KerMeta-UI-UserGuide/KerMeta-UI-UserGuide_figures/KerMeta_RunCommandLine_arguments.png))</sub>

And in Idea it is also, but in java SE, Java Eclipse.
I have build project with this tutorial
https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/getting-started.idea.html

and I can not find any place for this program arguments :)

When I run my project in idea it runs only Tomcat and deploys my software on it. And that's it.

Does anybody know where I can put this JProfiler settings to attach to my session in tomcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved :)
Install plugin in Intelij Idea 13 and it will integrate with IProfler :)

Answer (score 0):

JProfiler has an IDE integration for IntelliJ IDEA. Invoke "Session->IDE Integrations" in JProfiler an choose IntelliJ IDEA.

Then you will get a "Run->Profile" menu entry in IDEA and a toolbar button for profiling the selected run configuration.

Comment: unfortunetly I have a licence for JProfiler 7.2.3 :D and it cant integrate with Intelij 13 :) cause of license :)

Comment: The current IDEA plugin for JProfiler should work with JProfiler 7.2.3 You can download it from the IDEA plugin manager.